# React Spinbutton widget will not detect aria-labels

Tags: reactjs

To replicate the error: see the documentation for the NumberPicker widget here: https://jquense.github.io/react-widgets/api/NumberPicker/. Then, tab over to the widget and try stepping into the widget. The screen reader will not read off an aria-label for user access. For example, if there is a label above the widget that describes what it's supposed to do, the screen reader will not read it off. 
After going through the documentation and trying to make a custom label wrapper for it with an aria-label tag, I still can't seem to get the widget to cooperate. 
Are these widgets compatible with aria-labels at all? Thanks in advance and I hope I sufficiently explained the issue and where it occurs.

Answer (score 0):

The best I've got is to wrap it in a div with tabIndex="0" and your aria-label. This might be annoying as the user will have to tab again to move into the input field, maybe submit a feature request?